# Accessing private fields from other instances of the same class in F#

Tags: .net, f#

In C#, the following is allowed:

```
class A {
    private int i;

    public int lol(A a) {
        return a.i;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do something akin in F#? If yes, how? If not, what is the work-around?

My current class is something like:

```
type Point() =
  let mutable x = 0
  let mutable y = 0
  with
    member ...
```

Thanks

Comment: adding `member __.X with get() = x and set v =x <- v` should do what you want.

Comment: I see. Isn't there nothing less fancier?

Comment: If you don't mind hiding the private variable, you can use `member val X = 0 with get, set` which is a little simpler - see this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483467.aspx

Answer (score 3):

So there are a few different ways to do this

If you only want read only access you can do

```
type Point() =
  let mutable x = 0
  member __.X() = x
```

If you don't wan't the hidden variable you can use

```
member val X = 0 with get
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use val:

```
type A =
    val mutable private i: int

    new (n) = {i = n}

    member x.lol (a: A) = a.i


let objA1 = A(2)
let objA2 = A(5)

printfn "%d" <| objA2.lol(objA1)
printfn "%d" <| objA1.lol(objA2)
```